# How can I draw a Lewis structure?

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to draw a Lewis structure using `chemfig` package. I want something like this:

[image]

So far, I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\centering
\scalebox{6.5}{
\chemfig{\lewis{0:4:6:,F}-[:30]B(-[:90]\lewis{0:2:4:,F})(-[:-30]\lewis{0:4:6:,F})}
}       
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

How can I get a shorter bond length, a bigger font size, and color?

Comment: Do you want it colored?

Comment: I need shorter bond length as well as Bigger font size and color@CarLaTeX

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The length of the arm is set by a number after the angle of the arm: `:angle,length`. I used 0.6 for you.

The style of the dots can be changed with the fourth argument of `\setlewis`.

I didn't find a "pretty" way of changing the font color, so I just used `\textcolor` :P

The font size can be changed by changing the `\printatom` macro, inserting the font size before the `\ensuremath`.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{bm}

\setlewis[]{}{}{fill=yellow,very thin}

%\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\large\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\large\ensuremath{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\centering
\scalebox{6.5}{%
  \chemfig{%
    \textcolor{green}{B}
      ( -[:  90,0.6]\lewis{0:2:4:,\textcolor{orange}{F}})
      ( -[: -40,0.65]\lewis{0:4:6:,\textcolor{orange}{F}})
      ( -[:-140,0.65]\lewis{0:4:6:,\textcolor{orange}{F}})
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make the figure look even more like the OP's, one can tweak `\printatom` to `\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\large\ensuremath{\bm{\mathsf{#1}}}}` and connect `bm` package; this makes labels for chemical elements printed with bold sans-serif font.